# How to add a composite key in Pipeline identifier

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

I am setting up an import to get data from `Dynamics`, and the entity I am querying to has a composite unique key `(PlotId + CollectionId)`. which makes the record unique.
I am not able to find any example in Sitecore documentation.
I am using `Sitecore ver 9.2`

[image]

Both keys are GUID
Please suggest